# How can I get the description of a select multioptions tag in ZF?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

How can I get the description of a select multioptions tag in ZF?

If I do this, then I recieve the value, but a want the description

$subjectTitle = $feedbackForm->getValue('subjecttitle');

Comment: I've updated my answer, take a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `getDescription()` method on the element, something like:

```
<?php
$form->getElement('element_name')->getDescription();
```

Edit: OK, after figuring out what you want, here's a possible solution:

```
<?php
$options = $form->getElement('my_select')->getMultiOptions();
// on form submition then do
$value = $form->getValue('my_select');
echo $options[$value];
```

Comment: what do you mean by "selected description"? AFAIK 1 element has 1 description.

Comment: wen the user select one options, I want to now which he selected

Comment: you know, usually when someone provides the correct answer you accept it as the correct one -_-